# how do I print Ids of multiple buttons with same name in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

My code,

```
self.one = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add Button", pos = 100,20)
self.one.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addbt)
self.x = 50
self.idr = 0
self.btarr =  []


def addbt(self.event)      

    self.button = wx.Button(self, self.idr, "Button 1", pos = (self.x,100))
    self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnId)
    self.idr+=1
    self.x +=150

    self.btarr.append(self.button)



def OnId(self, Event):
    print "The id for the clicked button is: %d" % self.button.GetId() 
    #I wanna print id of indivual buttons clicked
```

I use the above code to create multiple buttons dynamically. All the created buttons have the same reference name. On clicking each button I should get respective  individual ids. But all I am getting is the ID of the last button created. How do I print indivual Ids of the buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your id is always 0 here

try setting idr to something that is unique (eg `wx.NewId()` )  or -1

or doing `self.idr = 0` in your `__init__` method

on a side note you should make self.button a list and append new buttons to it....

reassigning self.button to the new button each time may have funny side effects WRT garbage collection

Comment: Thanks! I have actually done it like that in my original program. Even if I create a list of buttons, how do it help me in getting the respective ids?

Comment: GetId() gets the id ... but you are setting it to self.idr right after you set `self.idr=0` so you are always setting the id to zero

Answer (score 0):

you must get the object that produced the event:

```
#create five buttons
for i in range(5):
    # I use different x pos in order to locate buttons in a row
    # id is set automatically
    # note they do not have any name ! 
    wx.Button(self.panel, pos=(50*i,50))  

#bind a function to a button press event (from any button)
self.Bind((wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnId)


def OnId(self, Event):
    """prints id of pressed button""" 
    #this will retrieve the object that produced the event
    the_button = Event.GetEventObject()

    #this will give its id
    the_id = the_button.GetId()

    print "The id for the clicked button is: %d" % the_id
```

Comment: @SwayamS. You have to accept and/or upvote the answers you find useful. You have not accepted any of the answers you got for your question on SO.

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to do that! Thanks again!